# Why is Enumeration in Collection Framework not defined for ArrayList objects where as it is defined for Vector objects?

Tags: java, collections

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList v1 = new ArrayList();
    v1.add(123);
    v1.add(153);
    v1.add(125);

    Enumeration en = v1.elements(); // This line gives error. 
    v1.add(4000);
    while(en.hasMoreElements())
    {
        System.out.println(en.nextElement());
    }

    System.out.println(v1);
}
```

Why there is an error in case of ArrayList but not in case of Vector?

Comment: Because, as [the documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) "_New implementations should consider using `Iterator` in preference to `Enumeration`._" . And, from the [documentation for `Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) "_it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`._". Basically both things you mention are **deprecated** and **should not be used**.

Comment: Although indeed there have been preferred alternatives for a long time, @Boris, neither `java.util.Vector` nor its `elements()` method is formally deprecated.

Comment: Whilst not formally deprecated - as in marked for removal - I argue that these are _effectively_ deprecated as the same recommendation not to use them in new code is given.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Enumeration` is a legacy class.
As the `Vector` class.
`List` and `Collection` more generally favor the use of `Iterator` to iterate on elements of them.
`Iterator` also provides a removal operation that `Enumeration` doesn't have.

You can read in the `Enumeration` javadoc :

> NOTE: The functionality of this interface is duplicated by the
>   Iterator interface. In addition, Iterator adds an optional remove
>   operation, and has shorter method names. New implementations should
>   consider using Iterator in preference to Enumeration.

Comment: I'm thinking it could be related to because of Enumeration supporting concurrency whereas arraylist being non-synchronized...

Comment: @AnantanujDey, `Enumeration` has no more or less support for concurrency than does `Iterator`.  Moreover, though `Vector` is indeed synchronized and `ArrayList` isn't, that does not constitute a reason why `ArrayList` couldn't have provided the same interface as Vector.  It's simply that Joshua Bloch and Sun decided to start fresh when they designed the Collections API.  They eased the forward transition by retrofitting the old `Vector` and `Hashtable` classes, but they chose not to be constrained by those and related classes' and interfaces' forms.

Comment: Thanx mate @JohnBollinger . I had some doubt, you cleared it :)